# Docker Desktop installation gone wrong - PC works like a server, can it be fixed?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, desktop

Docker Desktop installation went horribly wrong and lost all GUI aspects of the OS, it's now like a server login. Stupidly followed a video trying to learn. I was using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Jammy.

The video advised installation of docker engine. The following commands were used:

**Run the following command to uninstall all conflicting packages:**

```
$ for pkg in docker.io docker-doc docker-compose podman-docker containerd runc; do sudo apt-get remove $pkg; done
```

(this had found multiple files and removed them, although i can't remember ever installing before)

**Set up the repository**

1. Update the apt package index and install packages to allow apt to use a repository over HTTPS:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
```

2. Add Docker’s official GPG key:

```
$ sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
$ sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
```

3. Use the following command to set up the repository:

```
$ echo \
      "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
      "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
      sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

**Install Docker Engine**

1. Update the apt package index:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

2. Install Docker Engine, containerd, and Docker Compose. To install the latest version, run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
```

3. Verify that the Docker Engine installation is successful by running the hello-world image:

```
$ sudo docker run hello-world
```

At this point I started noticing things missing on the desktop GUI (file explorer, power off, etc.) then I panicked and performed the following:

**Uninstall Docker Engine**

1. Uninstall the Docker Engine, CLI, containerd, and Docker Compose packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin docker-ce-rootless-extras
```

2. Images, containers, volumes, or custom configuration files on your host aren’t automatically removed. To delete all images, containers, and volumes:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/containerd
```

I finished here with an update and upgrade and restarting, completely messed up, cannot update, all *failed, Ign, Err*

I'm thinking it has something to do with `echo` command, or the `for pkg in` one?

Comment: You told us what you did, but you provide very little information about the problems you are having now. For example, what do you mean by "things missing on the desktop GUI" - did icons disappear or the programs? What if you create a new user; does its desktop have file explorer? Also show us the results of `apt update` and describe whatever else is "completely messed up".

Comment: I would also focus on the `apt purge` command. /var/log/apt should tell you what exactly was removed. Perhaps reinstalling some of the packages that were removed as a consequence of the purge is sufficient. Of course, you would first have to fix *apt*, which is why I asked you about `apt update` errors and warnings.

Comment: **did icons disappear or the programs?** It seems the programs because eg. the file browser was completely different.

**What if you create a new user; does its desktop have file explorer?** After rebooting, at this point there is no desktop, just bash screen like a server (black screen).

**Also show us the results of apt update:-** This is very difficult because the list is so long but i can describe that all http archive have Ign in front of them, as well as some errors below, after these there is the list that says failed to fetch (all of the repos)